# Inheriting variables from parent scope in Javascript Modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, module

I'm working with Webpack modules to keep things organized in my projects, but something very annoying is having to explicitly specify all the variables that the module might need, instead of just having it search for them in the calling function's scope. Is there a better way to do it? Example:

main.js

```
import {logMonth} from "./helpers";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let month = "September";
  logMonth();
});
```

helpers.js

```
let logMonth = () => {
  console.log(month)
}
```

This will produce an error since `logMonth()` doesn't have access to the `month` variable.

This is an extremely simplified example, but for functions that need many variables, it can get pretty ugly to pass all the required arguments that the function might need.

My question is: Is there a way to make modules have access to the variables of the calling scope instead of explicitly passing them?

Comment: How about making `month` a parameter to the the function: `logMonth(month)`?

Comment: That's what I currently do when this is the case. However, imagine when the function needs several parameters that are already defined in the parent scope, then I would have to call `function(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)` which besides verbose, feels unnecessary since the variables are already there.

Comment: Once you have more than 3 parameters, use an object so you do not have to change any previously written calls to that function. So if you know in advance a function will grow to include more parameters, start off with an object as its sole parameter immediately and just add extra parameters as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but why would you want to? Modules are designed to prevent this. Always prefer pure functions, it's way easier to debug once the app becomes complicated.
Then you don't want to be searching multiple nested scopes from multiple modules for a bug, optimally you want to only be looking in the module that threw the error instead of every scope it has access to.

So `logMonth = month => console.log( month );` and `logMonth( 'September' );` is preferred.

You can use an object if you need to send multiple parameters to a function.
That way you do not have to change the function call signature in all places, you just add another (optional) parameter to the object:

`logMonths = ({ year, month, day}) => { ...do stuff... }`

This will work both with `logMonths({ month: 'september' })` as with `logMonths({ month: 'september', year: '2019' })`, so you never have to change like `logMonths( 'september' )` into `logMonths( null, 'september' )` and `logMonths( 2019, 'september' )` everywhere you used logMonths() before it had a year parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered a sneaky way to do this. I'll demonstrate with two JavaScript files. The first will be the top level file, and the second will be the module.

top-level.js

```
import {PipeLine} from './PipeLine.js';

App = {
    var1: 'asdf',
    var2: 'dfgh',

    method1: function() {
        // do something...
    },
}

pipeLine = new PipeLine(App);
```

PipeLine.js

```
export class Pipeline {
    constructor(app) {
        this.app = app;
        
        // Now do what you will with all the properties and methods of app.
    }
}
```